# Way to get a bunch of pictures combined (overlayed) in a responsive environment?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to place three pictures correctly: (TV, Content, Frame). On a static site it is easy. But how do I do it on a dynamic page? I would like fit the complete TV in the window. Is there a CSS-Solution or is it only possible with javascript? In my test-file I have tested some scripts, but without any success. Please have a look here: [myTest File](http://www.huntinggrounds.de/test)

Here my function I played with:

```
  function backgroundResize(){
         var windowH = $(window).height(); var windowW = $(window).width();
         var aspect_ratio = windowH / windowW;
    $('.background').each(function(i){
        var path = $(this);            // console.log(path);

        var contW = path.width();
        var contH = path.height();
        var imgW = path.attr("data-img-width");
        var imgH = path.attr("data-img-height");
        var ratio = imgW / imgH;
        // set img values depending on cont
        imgH = contH;
        imgW = imgH * ratio;
        // fix when too large
        if(contW > imgW){
            imgW = contW;
            imgH = imgW / ratio;
        }
       if (path.hasClass("fx-bg")){
                 path.find('img').css({width:contW*ratio + "px ", height: contH*ratio + "px"});
       };
       if (path.hasClass("fx-eyes")){
                path.find('img').css({ width:imgW*aspect_ratio + "px ", height: imgH*aspect_ratio + "px"});
                var t = (windowH-(imgH*aspect_ratio))/2;
                var l = (windowW-(imgW*aspect_ratio))/2;
                path.css({top: t + "px", left: l + "px"});
                console.log("eyes t:%s  -  l:%s",t,l);
       }
       if (path.hasClass("test")){

            $('main').css('max-width', imgW*aspect_ratio + 'px').css('max-height', imgH*aspect_ratio+'px');
                var tt = (windowH-(imgH*aspect_ratio))/2;
                var ll = (windowW-(imgW*aspect_ratio))/2;
                path.css({top: tt + "px", left: ll + "px"});
                console.log("test t:%s  -  l:%s",tt,ll);
       }


  });
}
```

Comment: try with css doing background:url();
background-size:cover;

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want done? It's not very clear currently.

Comment: As you can see in my example file. I would like to overlay the pictures in the right way that the TV fits.

Comment: @Medda86 I tested background-size: cover. But than I do not know how the picture is scaled. And I can't fit the overlay-picture in a right way.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all the images have the same parent or parent with exact same dimensions by making there parent position: relative. Then simply give all images this css:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* for old webkit browsers. */
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Remove all other css stuff.

I'm not sure if you are talking about this but, you can also down or upscale the images with a simple check and then apply transform scale to all images that makes everything fit its parent. You could have also made this with CSS only if all your images where of the same width and height using the max-width/height attributes.

Comment: Thx Reinout: Here you are centering all Images. But does it also fits the images?